# Counting number of times a value occurs

Tags: r

I have a variable (Var) which stores 10000 values and is of integer nature.

I want to count, how many times 1000 or higher than 1000 numeric value occurs in this list.

Any one liner in R?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sum(Var >= 1000)` will do it, as long as `Var` is a vector. If not, you'll need to tell R to find `Var` inside whatever object contains it. Here is an example:

```
> set.seed(2)
> Var <- sample(900:1100, 10)
> Var
 [1]  937 1040 1014  933 1085 1084  925 1061  990 1005
> Var >= 1000
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> sum(Var >= 1000)
[1] 6
```

This uses the fact that `TRUE` = 1 and `FALSE` = 0.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to do this for  " Var == 1000" , be sure to read up on the difference between "=="  and "all.equal"

Answer (score 10):

```
sum(Var>=1000)
```

Suggest you read some of the intro R docs, this kind of thing crops up all the time. Also, what you have is hopefully not a 'list' but a 'vector'. If it is a 'list' then... ummm, unlist() it first.

Comment: I think you meant `>=` not just `>`

Comment: @Spacedman: Thank you for the advice, I am playing with your script of MC simulation. What I want is to count number of times the observed overlap occurred in your variable sim and then divide it by the number of cycles. This will give some fraction which I think can be used as an empirical p-value. Any suggestions ?????

Comment: `mean(Var>=1000)` is a clever shorthand for `sum(Var>=1000)/length(Var)`

Answer (score 5):

perhaps not as efficient, but I like

```
> length(which(Var>=1000))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 sum(r >= 1000)
```

where r is a vector. This works because R automatically converts the booleans TRUE/FALSE to the values 1 and 0 when you try to sum a boolean vector.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use:

```
vec <- sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE)
table(vec > 2)
```

or

```
length(vec[vec>2])
```