# R calculate how many dups

Tags: r

I try to make extra column in this dataset to count how many time given pat_id present in the file (i.e. how many appointments hse had), appreciate your help.

```
pat_id; date; result
p123; 2015-4-5; ok
p02; 2015-6-8; ;
p123; 2015-8-8;miss
```

and desired output:

```
pat_id; total_appt; date; result
p123; 2; 2015-4-5; ok
p02; 1; 2015-6-8; ;
p123; 2; 2015-8-8;miss
```

Thanks much if you can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting number of times a value occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162546/counting-number-of-times-a-value-occurs)

Comment: Not very clear I must admit. Maybe `transform(df, total_appt = ave(as.character(pat_id), pat_id, FUN = length))`

Comment: @dd3 - I don't think that link is relevant here.  We need grouping on this data and this is also in data frame format.  That one is for a vector

Answer (score 1):

You can use data.table, assuming your data set is named data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, total_app := .N, by = pat_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your orginal data frame is "df"

```
countDf = data.frame(table(df$pat_id))
names(countDf) = c("pat_id","count")

df_with_count = merge(df,countDf,by="pat_id")
```