# Counting number of times a value occurs grouping by id in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset looks like below in `R`:    Found similar posts like this  [Counting number of times a value occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162546/counting-number-of-times-a-value-occurs) but not exactly the same.

```
id <-     c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,3)
cat.1 <-  c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
cat.2 <-  c("m","m","m","f","f","f","m","m","m","m")
score <-    c(-1,0,-1, 1,0,1, -1,0,1,1)


data <- data.frame("id"=id, "cat.1"=cat.1, "cat.2"=cat.2, "score"=score)
data
   id cat.1 cat.2 score
1   1     a     m    -1
2   1     a     m     0
3   1     a     m    -1
4   2     b     f     1
5   2     b     f     0
6   2     b     f     1
7   3     c     m    -1
8   3     c     m     0
9   3     c     m     1
10  3     c     m     1
```

I would like to count number of `-1` values in the `score` variable within each id. Also, I would like to keep the `cat.1` and `cat.2` variables. Desired output would be:

```
   id cat.1 cat.2 count(-1)
1   1     a     m    2
2   2     b     f    0
3   3     c     m    1
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: amisos55, you tag your question with [tag:plyr], which is less common on SO, often it seems people are looking for base-R, `dplyr`, or `data.table` solutions when looking at tabular data. Is that true here as well? There's no indication in your question that you're using anything not in base R. Answers may include any package (which is generally fine), but if you have specific needs or are leaning towards one in particular, it is often better to clearly state that in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
aggregate(score ~ ., FUN = function(x) sum(x == -1), data = data)

  id cat.1 cat.2 score
1  2     b     f     0
2  1     a     m     2
3  3     c     m     1
```

If you have more variables in your data and you want to group with just these three, then you can explicitly specify it by `aggregate(score ~ id + cat.1 + cat.2, ...)`

Comment: Variation on a  theme - `aggregate(cbind(score=score==-1) ~ ., FUN = sum, data = data)`

Answer (score 6):

This is something we can use `dplyr` for:

```
data %>%
    group_by(id, cat.1, cat.2) %>% # or: group_by_at(vars(-score))
    summarise(count_neg_1 = sum(score == -1))


#      id cat.1 cat.2 count_neg_1
# 1     1 a     m               2
# 2     2 b     f               0
# 3     3 c     m               1
```

You can change the name of the calculated column if you so desire. I generally avoid anything other than a letter, number, or underscore in my variable names.

Comment: `group_by_at(vars(-score))`

Comment: for some reason, I got this result using your function: ``count_neg_1
1           3``

Comment: That is strange @amisos55, I was able to get those results using the data you had on your question.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[ , sum(score == -1), by=c('id', 'cat.1', 'cat.2')]
#    id cat.1 cat.2 V1
# 1:  1     a     m  2
# 2:  2     b     f  0
# 3:  3     c     m  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `count`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(score = score == -1) %>% 
   dplyr::count(id, cat.1, cat.2, wt = score)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#    id cat.1 cat.2     n
#   <dbl> <fct> <fct> <int>
#1     1 a     m         2
#2     2 b     f         0
#3     3 c     m         1
```